# Spring Batch: Job dependencies

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-batch

I need to save 3 files to DB: A, B, C.
File B can not be inserted into DB before A, and file C can not be inserted before B.

 What would be the best approach to create dependencies between jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write one job with 3 steps: in step1 write file A to DB, in step2 write file B and in step3 write file C.

```
<job id="myJob>
  <step id="step1" next="step2"><!-- write file A --></step>
  <step id="step2" next="step3"><!-- write file B --></step>
  <step id="step3"><!-- write file C --></step>
</job>
```